# Sequelize syntax for where search

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, where-clause

**Hello everyone !** Small stupid question, after having scoured the web of course.

With sequelize, I want to add a second argument to where. That is to say that currently I am only looking for the email. I would like to add the username to it. Here is my basic code snippet:

```js
exports.signup = (req, res) => {
models
    .findOne({
      attributes: ['email'],
      where: {
        email:  Buffer.from(req.body.email).toString("hex")
      }
    })
 }
```

and I would like this sort of thing:

```js
models
    .findOne({
      attributes: ['email'] ['username'],
      where: {
      username: username,
        email:  Buffer.from(req.body.email).toString("hex")
      }
    })
```

```js
.findOne({
  attributes: ['email', 'username' ], // --> instead of ['email'] ['username']
  where: {
    username: req.body.username, // -> If you are getting username from the request body
    email:  Buffer.from(req.body.email).toString("hex")
  }
})

    .then(

      ((userFound) => {

          if (!userFound ) {

            bcrypt.hash(password, 10, function (err, bcryptPassword) {

              const newUser = models
                .create({
                  username: username,
                  email: Buffer.from(req.body.email).toString("hex"),
                  password: bcryptPassword,
                  bio: bio,
                  admin: false
                })

                .then((newUser) => {
                  res.status(201).json({
                    userId: newUser.id,
                    message: 'Merci, votre inscription est bien pris en compte !'
                  })
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                  res.status(500).json({
                    error: "Impossible d'ajouter un utilisateur",
                  })
                })

            })

          } else {
            return res.status(409).json({
              error: 'Ce compte existe déjà ',
            })
          }

      })
    )

}
```

I have tried several syntax, and also with the findAll method but I must go wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: @CyberEternal It does not put a particular error let's say rather that on postmann the request does not go to the end and turns into a vacuum.

Comment: Are you sure that without a username it works?

Comment: because if `signup` is your endpoint handler, looks like you are returning nothing as a response

Comment: @CyberEternal thank you, I just tried but it doesn't work, maybe my then which doesn't work, I just added the code in my first post

Comment: @CyberEternal, yes without username it works

Comment: The question is not clear. If you need information about how to use Sequelize, check the documentation first, please. https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html

Comment: If not helps, try to debug your code by adding logging.

Comment: @CyberEternal, ok i will see thank you anyway.